# Create time lapse video from other video

Tags: ffmpeg, avconv

Using avconv (or even ffmpeg, so I can use as a reference), how can I create a time lapse video by taking only anchor/reference frames from another video? Most information I find is on how to create a time lapse video by combining images, and I'd like to do it by extracting frames from a video. Say, if a video is 30 seconds long at 30 FPS, I'd like to take 60 out of those 900 frames (900/60 = every 15 seconds) to produce a 2 second video.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

To take every 15th frame, use the select filter

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf select='not(mod(n\,15))',setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB out.mp4
```

Another method is to use the framestep filter

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf framestep=15,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB out.mp4
```

Comment: Got different errors running both of these commands: "Missing ')' or too many args in 'mod(n'" and "Option 'framestep' not found"

Comment: For the first error, you probably need to escape the comma, so `n\,15` and for the 2nd, recheck the command string. If you were using a very old ffmpeg (before framestep filter was added), it would have complained `no such filter` but you're getting an `option` error, which indicates a malformed command. Are you using it in a shell or wrapper? What's the exact string?

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 16.10 with ffmpeg 3.0.7, and I'm copying and pasting your two command lines verbatim, only changing the in and out filenames.

Comment: Run the commands with `-report` added. A log will be written. Link to that.

Comment: For large videos (2-3 plus hours), I found framestep was drastically faster than using the select filter.

Comment: Yes, select will evaluate each frame for a match.

Comment: The first method works well but the framestep method above sets the output fps to 4 for me with a 60fps input.

Comment: Yes, it resets the framerate. To avoid that, `-vf framestep=15,setpts=N/60/TB,fps=60`

Comment: @Gyan -- Thank you, that did it.  I tried similar things but wasn't getting it right.  Didn't notice any speed improvements from the other method though.  But that is probably more a factor of the compression I'm doing on the way out than the filter method (and a video too short to notice much).

Comment: using `-vf framestep=15,setpts=N/60/TB,fps=60`, I get the appropriate playback speed. But the video keeps its original length, showing just the last frame for the remainder. How to trim the output to only the available frames at the given fps?

Comment: @AdamAL happened to me too. It turned out it was caused by the presence of the audio stream that was left present in the container. Simply adding `-an` to drop the audio stream solved the issue.

Comment: @AdamAL using `-an` was not enough for me, I had to use `-vf framestep=15,setpts=N/60/TB -r 60`. Effectively, move the setting of fps from `-vf` to `-r`. Full command is `ffmpeg -an -i in.mp4 -vf framestep=15,setpts=N/60/TB -r 60 out.mp4`.

Answer (score 13):

I had a H264 video from a camera and after lots of attempts found following command that produce 16x faster video with good result and 60 FPS (option -r) that is good for the YouTube timelapse

```
ffmpeg -i video.avi -r 60 -filter:v "setpts=0.0625*PTS" -vcodec libx264 -an timelapse.avi
```

You can check the result here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=azhRqKQ7kCU

Since you are asking for 1/15 frame it will be 1/15 ~= 0.06667 with 30 FPS result video you will need command

```
ffmpeg -i video.avi -r 30 -filter:v "setpts=0.06667*PTS" -vcodec libx264 -an timelapse.avi
```

Comment: What is the same command for mp4

Comment: @Jackie it should be the same. Just instead of typing in files ending in .avi, type in .mp4.

Answer (score 1):

When doing timelapses is useful to control the playback speed easily so I prefer the following approach:

- Speed: 60x (1 hour in 1 min, 1 min in 1 sec)
- Audio: No

```bash
ffmpeg -i in.avi -vf "setpts=PTS/60" -an out.mp4
```

Since the question is asking for a 2 second video and the original has 30 seconds length, the desired speed is 15x (i.e. 30/2 = 15), the command will be:

```bash
ffmpeg -i in.avi -vf "setpts=PTS/15" -an out.mp4
```