# FFmpeg Time Lapse from Sources with Long Frozen Tail End

Tags: ffmpeg, avi, timelapse

My source for inputs into `FFmpeg` is either one `AVI` file or a `concat` of many of them.  Either way my resulting timelapse file has a long tail of frames that are a repeat of a single frame.  It's like a very long freeze frame is resulting on the end of my output file.

I'm on an older `Mac Pro` so I can't update my `FFmpeg`.  I have a laptop that has a newer version and I get the same there as well.  I'm not sure if it's because my source files are `AVI` or not.

```
ffmpeg version 4.1.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
    built with Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)
    configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.1.1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags=-I/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Headers/ --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-videotoolbox --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-libaom --enable-libsoxr
    libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
    libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
    libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
    libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
    libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
    libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
    libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
    libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
    libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
[avi @ 0x7fa82080c800] sample size (1) != block align (2)
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.1 : mono
Input #0, avi, from 'concat:16460001.AVI|16460002.AVI|16460003.AVI|16460004.AVI|16460005.AVI|16460006.AVI|16460007.AVI|16460008.AVI|16460009.AVI|16460010.AVI|16460011.AVI|16460012.AVI|16460013.AVI|16460014.AVI|16460015.AVI|16460016.AVI|16460017.AVI|16460018.AVI|16460019.AVI|16460020.AVI|16460021.AVI':
    Duration: 00:10:02.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 365923 kb/s
        Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (MJPG / 0x47504A4D), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1280x720, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
        Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 32000 Hz, mono, s16, 512 kb/s
Stream mapping:
    Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> h264 (libx264))
    Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (pcm_s16le (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x7fa82082cc00] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.1 Cache64
[libx264 @ 0x7fa82082cc00] profile High, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 0x7fa82082cc00] 264 - core 155 r2917 0a84d98 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2018 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=16 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'out.mp4':
    Metadata:
        encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
        Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, progressive), 1280x720, q=-1--1, 16 fps, 16384 tbn, 16 tbc
        Metadata:
            encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 libx264
        Side data:
            cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
        Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 32000 Hz, mono, fltp, 69 kb/s
        Metadata:
            encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 aac
frame= 1962 fps=1.2 q=-1.0 Lsize=  136725kB time=03:24:07.00 bitrate=  91.5kbits/s dup=0 drop=365448 speed=7.41x
video:31548kB audio:103624kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 1.149437%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa82082cc00] frame I:10    Avg QP:18.74  size: 62176
[libx264 @ 0x7fa82082cc00] frame P:514   Avg QP:21.24  size: 30528
[libx264 @ 0x7fa82082cc00] frame B:1438  Avg QP:22.74  size: 11121
[libx264 @ 0x7fa82082cc00] consecutive B-frames:  1.4%  2.0%  2.0% 94.6%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa82082cc00] mb I  I16..4:  2.1% 97.2%  0.7%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa82082cc00] mb P  I16..4:  2.0% 33.3%  0.1%  P16..4: 37.7% 12.0% 10.4%  0.0%  0.0%    skip: 4.5%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa82082cc00] mb B  I16..4:  0.7% 11.5%  0.0%  B16..8: 29.1%  4.8%  1.3%  direct:12.0%  skip:40.6%  L0:47.5% L1:42.9% BI: 9.6%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa82082cc00] 8x8 transform intra:94.3% inter:83.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa82082cc00] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 73.4% 66.7% 8.5% inter: 25.9% 46.8% 2.2%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa82082cc00] i16 v,h,dc,p: 17% 33% 26% 24%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa82082cc00] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 13% 23% 51%  1%  2%  1%  4%  1%  2%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa82082cc00] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 17% 21% 19%  5%  8%  7% 13%  5%  5%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa82082cc00] i8c dc,h,v,p: 46% 29% 23%  2%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa82082cc00] Weighted P-Frames: Y:47.5% UV:19.3%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa82082cc00] ref P L0: 45.0% 13.8% 20.6% 15.7%  5.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa82082cc00] ref B L0: 61.1% 30.4%  8.5%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa82082cc00] ref B L1: 85.8% 14.2%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa82082cc00] kb/s:2107.54
[aac @ 0x7fa82081ea00] Qavg: 130.084
```

I've read this thread and tried to follow it:

[Create time lapse video from other video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41902160/create-time-lapse-video-from-other-video)

Here are some trials I've attempted before, all with the same output:

```
# ffmpeg -y -i $mov -vf framestep=10,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB,fps=2 -r 30 $out
# ffmpeg -y -i $mov -vf framestep=10,setpts=.01*PTS -r 30 $out
# ffmpeg -y -i $mov -vf framestep=10,setpts=.1*PTS -r 30 $out
# ffmpeg -y -i "concat:16460001.AVI|16460002.AVI|16460003.AVI|16460004.AVI|16460005.AVI|16460006.AVI|16460007.AVI|16460008.AVI|16460009.AVI|16460010.AVI|16460011.AVI|16460012.AVI|16460013.AVI|16460014.AVI|16460015.AVI|16460016.AVI|16460017.AVI|16460018.AVI|16460019.AVI|16460020.AVI|16460021.AVI" -vf framestep=10,setpts=.05*PTS -r 30 $out
ffmpeg -y -i "concat:16460001.AVI|16460002.AVI|16460003.AVI|16460004.AVI|16460005.AVI|16460006.AVI|16460007.AVI|16460008.AVI|16460009.AVI|16460010.AVI|16460011.AVI|16460012.AVI|16460013.AVI|16460014.AVI|16460015.AVI|16460016.AVI|16460017.AVI|16460018.AVI|16460019.AVI|16460020.AVI|16460021.AVI" -r 16 -filter:v "setpts=0.01*PTS" out.mp4
```

Am I overlooking something?  I'm trying to speed up the inputs into a single file to quickly review incoming security footage.  How can I do this without the super long useless tail at the end?

Comment: Do you need the audio? Add `-an` and check,

Comment: I want to avoid audio altogether.  Did some trials for two source files and those frames are still there, deaf and otherwise.  `ffmpeg -y -an -i "concat:16460001.AVI|16460002.AVI" -r 16 -filter:v "setpts=0.01*PTS" $out_deaf
ffmpeg -y -i "concat:16460001.AVI|16460002.AVI" -r 16 -filter:v "setpts=0.01*PTS" $out`

Comment: Even single file, deaf and otherwise, still retaining 10:02 in length, with the tail of it being a repeated frame.

Comment: Share a couple of these files.

Comment: No clue where to post this source file.  Any ideas?  1.34 GB

Comment: Dropbox, Drive..etc

Comment: One hour or so:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/f9dywnnn2wflxoq/16460021.AVI?dl=0

Comment: Just realized the deaf version maintains the audio track for some reason.  See above.

Comment: Unless you're using a recent version of ffmpeg, `-an` should be after the inputs.

Comment: Got a test to work...`-an` was placed in the wrong location.

Comment: Now `-an` isn't working:  `ffmpeg -y -i /Volumes/RUN_SD16/DCIM/10090704/14080016.AVI -vf framestep=15,setpts=N/30/TB,fps=30 -an /users/rich/desktop/final_run.mp4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i 16460021.AVI -vf framestep=15,setpts=N/30/TB -r 30 -an out.mp4
```

I get an output 1/15th the length of the original. When using framestep=X, setpts should be of the form `N/X/TB` if you wish to avoid frame duplication. Don't use `fps` when compressing video duration as it uses old stream duration from before compression (a bug). Skip audio, since that will result in original length.

Comment: OK that worked for a single file.  I'm working with an old version, and I wanted to see the faster route of the two approaches.  Taking out the audio fixed the bad tail.  Thank you.